# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , react_redux_1.connect) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to make the legacy react code work using latest version of redux ("redux": "^5.0.1").
I have this legacy code as part of package (generated from a different project using npm pack). In the main application, i am calling this component, and it fails with below error -

Uncaught TypeError: (0 , react_redux_1.connect) is not a function
at ./node_modules/@test/common-package/dist/authentication/components/LoginCallback.js (LoginCallback.tsx:20:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:22:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
at ./node_modules/@test/common-package/dist/authentication/index.js (index.ts:1:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:22:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
at ./node_modules/@test/common-package/dist/reducers/index.js (index.ts:2:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)

Here is the sample code for the component in package for your reference:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxEMg.png

it fails in this code - const connector = connect(undefined,mapDispatchToProps);

Any idea what might be going wrong here?

**Edit:** If i use the connect directly from the main application, without using package, it works fine. But the connect does not work, if i use it in package.

Comment: I have managed to solve this issue. For those who are struck with similar issue, i have created a repo for you to check. This is using component library which is used in another project. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-yjkn3u?file=package.json,components-library%2Fpackage.json

Ensure that in your component library, all the packages that depend on react/react-dom are moved to peerDependencies. Look at below issue resolution for details.
https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1982